Unity で VRChat 用アバターのギミック導入時のエラーの対処法は？
ギミックは視界に時刻を表示したりするHUDギミックです。
ギミックのRequirementsが以下の通りです。
◊ Unity 2022+
◊ VRChat Avatar SDK 3.6.0+
◊ VRCFury 1.859.0+
◊ Final IK Stub
サイトにある手順の通りにしたのですが上の画像のエラーが出てアバターをアップロードできませんでした。
初心者なので意味などを調べてもよく理解できず、対処法が分かる方がいれば助けてくださるとうれしいです。
表示されたエラー

現在のパッケージ

